# Change checked status of selected cell from uiTableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm new to swift and trying to change selected tableviewcell checked. 
I'm trying to; user select city and districts and click to save button and app send the informations to server. There is no problem so there. When user wants to update the city or districts, I should check before districts and user can see what is he/she select or not. I'm getting first informations from server with json and append them to array. When user click the update button I can see before selected informations in debug mode but tableview cells are not going to be as checked. Sorry for my bad English btw.

**What am I doing for first time selection :**

```
in viewDidLoad()
        self.tableViewDistrict.isEditing = true
        self.tableViewDistrict.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.tableViewDistrict.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectDeselectCell(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    }

extension ViewController{
    func selectDeselectCell(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath){
        self.selectedDistId.removeAll()
        if let array = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows{
            for index in array{
                selectedDistId.append(districtArray[index.row].id!)
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you storing the previously selected districts ?

Comment: They are storing to server side. When user wants to update them I'm getting from the server and append to array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets suppose you have stored all your previous selected data inside an array like

```
var alreadySelectedDistricts : [String] = []
```

so in your cellForRowAt method you can do a check like

```
for district in alreadySelectedDistricts { 
    if cell.districtLabel.text.contains(district) { 
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    } else { 
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
}
```

Comment: Vouv bro thank you! It is not worked but when i use it as "cell.backgroundColor" it is worked correctly.

Comment: glad to help .. Please accept the answer if it helped.